# Functioning of enter key in fancybox - the same photo is opened over the previous one and so on infinitely

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a strange problem with functioning of enter key in fancybox. When I press it the selected photo of gallery is opened, if I press it again the same photo is opened over the 
previous one and so on infinitely. 
At same time in the page where I have the fancybox gallery if I try to use the search box when I press enter key selected photo of gallery is opened instead of submit the search form. 
Here you can see an example: https://flexteam2.power-app.net/albert_sofa/

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

1) Since you can start fancybox on your page just by pressing Enter key at any time (e.g., without doing anything, without clicking on the links, etc); 2) This issue appears only on your site; - I can assume that this is caused by your custom code. The only advice I can give you is to clean up your page, remove various bits until everything starts working fine. Start by disabling WP plugins.

You can easily check that this issue is not caused by fancybox itself - 1) click on the link; 2) open developer tools (hit F12 and open Console tab) and paste `document.activeElement` - it will show currently active element and you will see that it will be set correctly (e.g., active element is not the link, but `.fancybox-container` element and therefore hitting Enter would not trigger fancybox from the link).